# Display JSON response w/ recursion

Tags: jquery, json, recursion

I've constructed a JQuery function which attempts to display all the contents of a JSON object returned back from a server. Currently, I'm using an iterative approach (by looping through every node) but I'm trying to apply recursion. Please provide some suggestions.

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (response) {
        for (var key1 in response) {
            var post1 = response[key1];
            console.log(key1 + ": " + post1);
            for (var key2 in post1) {
                //debugger Object[0]
                var post2 = post1[key2];
                console.log(key2 + ": " + post2);
                for (var key3 in post2) {
                    //etc
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Breakout the console code into a simple recursive function and pass the "root" object to it. Something like:

```
function dumpIt(obj){
    for (var key1 in obj) {
        var post1 = obj[key1];
        console.log(key1 + ": " + post1);
        // Go recursive on each child object
        dumpIt(post1);
    }
}

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (response) {
        dumpIt(response);
    }
});
```

Slightly more robust version - with indenting:

```
function dumpIt(obj, indent) {
    if (typeof obj == "object") {
        for (var key1 in obj) {
            var post1 = obj[key1];
            console.log(indent + key1 + ": " + post1);
            // Go recursive on each child object
            dumpIt(post1, indent + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Call like: `dumpIt(obj, "");`

### Sample JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/r9PYm/2/

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll base my implementation with a similar logic.